# analyzing the data in R

Tags: r

[image]

I am trying to analyze my data set and I am having a struggle with it.
I want to get mean and standard deviation but as you can see from picture, when I use `summary(West)` it doesn't give me mean or max or min etc.

What's wrong with my data set?

Comment: formatting an more appropriate tag. You should NOT use a picture to show your data and code - include them as text. Use `dput(head(Houseprice))`

Comment: my guess is that `Houseprice$West` is a factor, not a numeric variable. If you have commas as the decimal separator, you need to allow for this when importing the data